# Sigma summation in Excel for accumulated value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how can I use an iterative summation in Excel to compute the accumulated value starting amount (stored in one column) which escalates at 5 % p.a for n years (stored in another column) with the resultant amount then being subjected to a constraint. In essence, the raw function looks like:

[image: \sum ^n_{0=:\left(1.05^n\right)\left(0.1x\right)-80}]

where x = starting amount in a column, constraint is 10% of the amount less 80

Also, is my raw function okay to compute the accumulated value with the constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To sum just one year:**

Put n in cell A1, put x in cell A2:

`=1.05^A1*0.1*A2-80`

That will give you the value you're looking for.

**To sum all of the years less than (and including) n down to 1:**

Put n in cell A1, put x in cell A2:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1.05^ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&A1))*(0.1*A2)-80)`

Much the same, except that it's wrapped in a SUMPRODUCT() to allow for array formulas and the value given for n will return all positive integers less than (and including) n. The calculation is repeated n times and the result summed.

**To sum all years less than (and including) n down to zero**

`=SUMPRODUCT(1.05^(-1+ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&A1+1)))*(0.1*A2)-80)`

Same as answer #2, except it includes zero.

Comment: I believe that will give me an answer for the specific years, for example, the value at year 4.
And not a value that has accumulated over years 0,1,2,3, and 4.

Right?

Comment: That's correct, did I misunderstand the question? I'll edit it to add an answer to the second scenario too.